# How to copy selector id into li selector class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  groups = $('[id^=id_2_class_]');    
    $.each(groups, function(key, group) {
        inputs = $(group).attr('id'); 
        alert(inputs);
        $()
    });
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="id_2_class_385">id_2_class_385</div>
<div id="id_2_class_386">id_2_class_386</div>
<div id="id_2_class_387">id_2_class_387</div>
<div id="id_2_class_388">id_2_class_388</div>

<ul class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Above is my current code, how can I transfer the selector id into another element's class using jquery?

The result should look like the below

```
<div id="id_2_class_385">id_2_class_385</div>
<div id="id_2_class_386">id_2_class_386</div>
<div id="id_2_class_387">id_2_class_387</div>
<div id="id_2_class_388">id_2_class_388</div>

<ul class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
    <li class="id_2_class_385">1</li>
    <li class="id_2_class_386">2</li>
    <li class="id_2_class_387">3</li>
    <li class="id_2_class_388">4</li>
    <li class="id_2_class_389">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: question is not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: A fiddle would help tremendously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the IDs, just need to add them to the list items like so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    groups = $('[id^=id_2_class_]');
    groups.each(function (index) {
        inputs = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.flex-control-nav').find('li').eq(index).addClass(inputs);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jvqq23kv/

Basically just go through each li and add the class

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
This goes through each one and creates an `<li>` so it doesn't matter how many you have. It creates dynamically.

```
$(function(){
    $('[id^=id_2_class_]').each(function(){
    $('ul.flex-control-nav.flex-control-paging').append("<li id='"+this.id+"'></li>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pLvopvqL/

Comment: lis are regenerated Bharanikumar wanted to copy ids only